# @IBAction func pinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)を実装したControllerを他のプロジェクトに組み込むと動作しない

Tags: swift4

`@IBAction func pinch()`が単独のプロジェクトでは動いたのですが、他のプロジェクトに組み込むとやはり動きません。何が原因か教えて頂けませんか。
(5つ程度のコントローラーの中の一つです)

```swift
class PinchController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

   @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet var pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      pinchRecognizer.delegate = self
   }

   @IBAction func pinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
       // --- イメージをドラッグしてもこの処理に移動しない
   }
}
```

前回`@IBAction func pinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)`に処理が移動しないと質問した結果、設定が間違っていたので動いたというのは勘違いのようでした。

組み込んだ時に下記 @IBOurlet,@IBAction共に改めて繋ぎ直してあります。

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer!
@IBAction func pinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    // --- イメージをドラッグしてもこの処理に移動しない
}
```

Comment: `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`のインスタンス`pinch`は、Storyboard上で生成され、その大半をStoryboard上で編集されているはずです。なので「他のプロジェクト」のStoryboardでも、同一の編集を行わないと、ソースコードを移植しただけでは、動きません。この点について、質問文の追加編集をしていただければと思います。

Comment: @IBOUTLET,@IBACTION共に追加で編集しています。

Comment: @IBOUTLET,@IBACTION共に追加で編集しています。ソースを追加する時にSWIFT FilEで作成するのとCOCOA TOUCH CLASSで作るのは違いが有るのでしょうか ?

Comment: 私は「 **質問文の** 追加編集をして」くださいとコメントしたのであって、「 **@IBOUTLET,@IBACTION** 」を追加編集とは言っておりません。質問文の編集がなければ、これ以上コメントも回答もするつもりはありませn。